# Combine two documents into one in mongo

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I`m working on some aggregation pipeline.
My previous step ends with two following documents:

```json
{ x: 1, y: 60, z: 111}
```

and

```json
{ x: 1, y: 90, z: 222}
```

I'm using `x` as `id` and want to combine two documents to be like:

```
{ x: 1, y1: { z: 111 }, y2: { z: 222} }
```

any help would be appreciated

I've been trying to `"$group"` them by `x` value, but at the end still have array; and after `"$unwind"` step it's back to two documents.

Comment: You can use $group. Please share your current query

Comment: Your approach using `$group` to create a doc like `{_id: 1, q: [ {y:60,z:111}, {y:90,z:222} ]}` seems like the better way.  Why the need to create new keys (y1 and y2) and lose their values?

Comment: i dont lose values, i need to transform data under new filed.

Comment: Is the ordering of `y1`, `y2`, ... important?  I.e., should the _original_ `y` values be considered when assigning `y1`, `y2`, etc.?  BTW, I'm curious why losing the _original_ `y` values is desired.

Comment: for example Y have some int value that represents contact preferences (phone or email). so in final document i need to represent the Z value depending on what was Y, and it could be only one or bougth of them. you can think of Y1 and Y2 as values of origin Y : { x: 1, 60: { z: 111 }, 90: { z: 222} }, and Z represent id in another collection.

Answer (score 1):

As much as I believe using `$group` to hold onto the `y` and `z` is best, I submit this solution as an example of how to use `$reduce` as a `for` loop and the power of `$arraytoObject` to dynamically construct lvals (fields) in a pipeline.

```js
c=db.foo.aggregate([
    // Push only an object of the things we need later; in this
    // case it is just 'z'.  Try changing to:
    //   {$push: {z:'$z',y:'$y'}}
    // and watch what happens.
    {$group: {_id: "$x", X: {$push: {z:"$z"}}}}

    // Iterate over X and dynamically build k-v pairs for the
    // upcoming arrayToObject.  
    // Note we $project input X over existing X because there is no point
    // in carrying the original array through the pipeline:
    ,{$project: {X: {$reduce: {
        input: '$X',

        // The value (stateful) part of the loop will contain a
        // counter n and the array newX which we will rebuild with
        // the help of n:
        initialValue: {
            n:0,  // counter
            newX:[]
        },
        in: {$let: {
          vars: {qq:{$add:['$$value.n',1]}}, // n = n + 1
          in: {
            n: '$$qq', // must carry over count in the loop!

            // This is the juice.  Append to the array using
            // $concatArrays.  Note the dynamic construction
            // of the field name k (for example, it will
            // become 'y1', 'y2, etc.   Note also v captures
            // whatever we pushed earlier, which in this particular
            // case is {z:value}:
            newX: {$concatArrays: [
                '$$value.newX',
                // Must concat an array of one object, not just an object:
                [ {'k':{$concat:['y',{$toString:'$$qq'}]},'v':'$$this'} ]
            ]}
        }
        }}
        }}
    }}

    /*
      All data is now set up.  To get a sense of what is happening,
      comment out this last stage and look at the "before" output.
    */
    ,{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$mergeObjects: [
        {x: '$_id'},
        {$arrayToObject: '$X.newX'}
        ]}
    }}
]);
```

Comment: FYI, here's a [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3IcfK_yLnAH) demonstrating your aggregation pipeline.

Comment: looks like working solution, really appreciate it. hope it will work on mongo 4.4

Comment: @dankosorkin Edited to remove `$getField` which appeared in v5.0.  Instead, the following stage extracts the array with `$X.newX`.  Now 4.4 compatible.